# Setting LicenseType property of Azure SQL Database to enable Azure Hybrid Use Benefit (AHUB) using Terraform?

Tags: azure-sql-database, terraform-provider-azure, azure-elasticpool

Using Terraform, how do I set the Azure SQL Database (and Azure Elastic Pool) LicenseType property to enable Azure Hybrid Use Benefit (aka AHUB, aka AHB)?

Here's an example using Powershell:

```
# Azure SQL Database:
Set-AzSqlDatabase -DatabaseName $sqlDb.DatabaseName -ResourceGroupName $sqlDb.ResourceGroupName -ServerName $sqlDb.ServerName -LicenseType "BasePrice"

# Azure SQL Database Elastic Pool:
Set-AzSqlElasticPool -ElasticPoolName $elasticPool.elasticPoolName -ResourceGroupName $elasticPool.ResourceGroupName -ServerName $elasticPool.ServerName -LicenseType "BasePrice"
```

The property is easily set using Az CLI too.

This is a very important property (from a cost perspective) and I cannot find mention of it anywhere in the context of Terraform.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Terraform documentation

license_type - (Optional) Specifies the license type applied to this database. Possible values are LicenseIncluded and BasePrice.

Here is the link 
https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/mssql_elasticpool.html#license_type

Comment: Thanks @alexey that helps for Azure SQL Database Elastic Pools, however, it doesn't address Azure SQL Databases that are not associated with Elastic Pools.  Any idea how it's done on a singleton database outside of a pool?

Comment: Oh! Found something very promising: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/mssql_database.html

Answer (score 0):

Why does it seem `LicenseIncluded` = the "Save Money" box being unchecked. I would have thought `LicenseIncluded` would have add the box checked and `BasePrice` would be unchecked, but in practice it is the opposite.

Comment: I guess the logic is `BasePrice` - only pay for infra (since you already have licenses somewhere else), and `LicenseIncluded` - also pay licensing fees, because you want licenses included with this offering.

Answer (score 0):

Hashicorp's site doesn't make this setting clear. The setting description is present, but the expanded description of the possible values is not. Combining Hashicorp's site with Microsoft's, we get:

license_type - (Optional) Specifies the license type applied to this database. Possible values are:

- 'LicenseIncluded' if you need a license
- 'BasePrice' if you have a license and are eligible for the Azure Hybrid Benefit

Sources:

- https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/mssql_database#license_type
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.sql.models.database.licensetype?view=azure-dotnet